# Error: Audio Priority Boost

Tags: android, audio, csound

Using CSound for Android I get this (appearantly harmless) error:

```
E/AudioTrack: did not receive expected priority boost on time
```

What does it mean? How can I boost this Audio priority?

Comment: @beppis Did you find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is related to the way that Android temporarily elevated the priority of the FastMixer and AudioTrack callbacks threads, as to prevent priority-inversion. According to the docs, this log message appears when the request to shift the priority does not succeed.

[Google's log](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/f8197a6%5E!/)

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very detailed. But I fail to understand how to fix this, do you have any solution? How can I request this priority shift? I'm totally confused :D Thank you very much. Anyway, according to that document, it looks like this does not have impact on runtime, but only in initialization, do you confirm this?

Comment: I also think that it should not affect the performance after the initial jitter but have not tested it myself so I cannot tell you for sure, in that case it looks like an internal implementation thing.